# How to insert a second title row for a csv file using C# code in script task SSIS

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, csv, ssis

I have a csv file generated by export package using SSIS. I need to insert a row at the title level.
My present CSV file looks like this :

```
Company;country;name;id;address
XXX;yyy;ZZZ;00;wwwwwwwwwww
```

I need to add a row above the header, it looks like :

```
sap;vvv;nnn;aaaa;count
Company;country;name;id;address
XXX;yyy;ZZZ;00;wwwwwwwwwww
```

Comment: you will get check Box to use as Header then why this requirement serves the Purpose

Comment: i need 2 header lines , ssis generats a file with only one Header .

Comment: CSV files are **_Comma-Separated Values_**, and all column headers should be on the first line of the file. Can you explain why you need headers on two lines (if possible, also with an example)? Maybe there is a better way to solve your actual problem.

Comment: the number of columns are fixe or dynamic ?